# Virtual Box fix processor and graphics controller

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm using Linux. I ran Virtual Box as an administrator to control the number of processors and graphics controller. But I cannot change anything. What can I do for that?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Stop the VM. You can't change these settings while the VM is running.

Comment: Thank you, but I failed to save the settings of the virtual machine. Error message is that Failed to save the settings of the virtual machine WIN10 to /root/VirtualBox VMs/WIN10/WIN10.vbox.

Runtime error opening '/root/VirtualBox VMs/WIN10/WIN10.vbox-tmp' for overwriting: -102 (File not found.).

/home/vbox/vbox-6.0.8/src/VBox/Main/src-server/MachineImpl.cpp[10020] (nsresult Machine::i_saveSettings(bool*, int)).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}

Comment: How are you starting VirtualBox as root? When does this error message appear?

Comment: After I access to the administrator through code 'su' in terminal, I type VirtualBox 'root@thebiophys4:/home/jae/Desktop# VirtualBox VMS'. This error message appears when I try to save this changed setting by clicking 'Ok' button.

Comment: I don't think you have to run it as root to change these settings. Try as a regular user (add yourself to the `vboxusers` group first: `adduser $USER vboxusers`). You won't be able to access that VM as it's owned by root, but you can create a new one just for the sake of test. You can also try to run VBox as root using `gksu` of `pkexec` instead of `su`, it can cause issues with graphical applications.